# Trigger selenium project without human intervention

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have completed automation script of my project. Now client wants to run selenium test case using URL or API. Client is not interested in Jenkins as well since they should need access for my project.

Overall client wants to trigger selenium without human intervention.

Any other idea than above is also welcome.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: You could provide them with a VM that has everything installed and a link to a shell script that runs the test on the desktop, then they can just double click on the desktop.  Honestly, this is just too broad.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide command line or batch file depends on TestFramework(TestNg, Nunit, MsTest).

For e.g. You can use Mstest/TestContainer:Dll_Name ......some more parameters.

For TestNg, You can use Java "Jar file path" org.testing.TestNG testconfig.xml

Here i am just giving hints to you. Correct way to do it will depend on test framework used.